# Metric spaces: patching uniform continuity from subsets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space, and $A$, $B$ be closed subsets of $X$ (not necessarily disjoint) with $A \cup B = X$.

Suppose I have a function $f : X \to Y$, for $(Y, d')$ some other metric space, and I know that $f \mid_{A}$ and $f \mid_{B}$ are both uniformly continuous (in the subspace metrics of $A$ and $B$). Does it follow that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $X$?

(EDIT: As pointed out in the comments, I should probably be assuming $X$ is complete; and it does follow that $f$ is continuous on $X$.)

(I have an ugly proof for the case $X = \mathbb{R}$, which would probably also work for an arbitrary Riemannian manifold; but I'd be interested to know if it works for general metric spaces $X$. Ideally, one would want a proof for [uniform spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space) without using metrics at all, but maybe that's too much to ask.)

Comment: Your first line is already confusing. If $A, B \subseteq X$ and $A \cap B = X$, then $A=B=X$.

Comment: I’m assuming you meant $X=A\cup B$ instead. If so, you may want to assume completeness. While I buy that this holds for $\Bbb{R}$, it won’t hold for subspaces of $\Bbb{R}$, such as $\Bbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. The sign function, mapping positive numbers to $1$ and negative numbers to $-1$, will be uniformly continuous on closed subspaces $(0, \infty)$ and $(-\infty, 0)$, but not on all of $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant $A \cup B = X$ (and I'm happy to assume completeness, to eliminate Theo's example).

Comment: The first bullet ("$f$ is continuous") follows from the second bullet.

Comment: @Ulli Indeed it does, good point.

Comment: Considering Theo Bendit's counter-example, isn't it more a question of connectness rather than completeness? For instance, let $X := \{(x, |\frac{1}{x}|): x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \}$. Then $X$ is the disjoint union of two open sets $A, B$, such that $d(A,B) = 0$. The function mapping $A$ to $-1$ and $B$ to $1$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ and $B$, but not on $X$. Moreover, the above $X$ is complete with respect to the standard metric.

Comment: @Ulli Connectedness feels wrong too. Take your $X$, $A$, and $B$, and extend them to $X', A', B'$, defined by $X \cup L, A \cup L, B \cup L$ respectively, where $L$ is the line segment between $(1, 1)$ and $(-1, 1)$ (if I understand your sets correctly, this will make $X$, $A$, and $B$ all connected. Extend your function to $X'$, interpolating linearly (or otherwise continuously) along $L$. Then $X$ is uniformly continuous on $A$ and $B$, but not on $X$.

Comment: We may have to retreat all the way back to compactness of $A$ or $B$. This feels too strong of an assumption, however.

Comment: @Theo Bendit: yes, I also thought about a similar one. If $X$ is restricted to $-1 \le x \le 1$ the resulting space is even homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ (as a topological space, not as a metric space), hence it is a (connected) manifold.

Comment: @Ulli, Theo: nice counterexample! I'd be happy to accept that as an answer if one of you wants to post it as such.

Comment: @Ulli Why don't you do it? You've thought about it as much as me, and I'm about to go to bed.

Comment: Well, we found a volunteer posting these examples as an answer ...

Answer (score 0):

Completeness is not enough: Let $A$ be the graph $y = 1/x$ and $B$ the graph $y = -1/x$ in the plane, and use Theo's example ($f = 1$ on $A$, $-1$ on $B$).

Because we can play the same game with any pair of disjoint, non-empty closed subsets, we really need to ensure that
$$
d(A, B) = \inf \{d(a, b) : a \in A, b \in B\}
$$
is positive. Compactness of either $A$ or $B$ is sufficient (exercise from Rudin's *Principles of mathematical Analysis*, if memory serves), but not generally necessary. (Think of subsets of a discrete metric space, where every function is uniformly continuous and all subsets are closed, but only finite subsets are compact.)